# In Ubuntu Lucid, various panel applets malfunction on login

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gnome

I run Ubuntu 10.04 with KDE installed as a second environment. When I log into a GNOME session, some of my panel applets appear strangely. It isn't always the same ones but the usual culprits are the notification area and the session indicator applet. The icons are cut off, or sometimes missing entirely. The only solution I've found is to remove them from the panel and re-add them but I'm looking for a better fix. Has anyone had this issue before?